# ДЗ Hospital результат 32.133.132.533.534.536.538.539.533. температуру пациентов+ на одного здорового меньше чем нужно(

Tags: java

public class Hospital {

```
public static float[] generatePatientsTemperatures(int patientsCount) {


    float[] patientsTemperature = new float[patientsCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < patientsCount; i++) {
        patientsTemperature[i] = Math.round(((float) (Math.random() * 8) + 32) * 100) / (float) 100.0;
        System.out.print(patientsTemperature[i]);
    }

    return patientsTemperature;
}

public static String getReport(float[] temperatureData) {
    int count  = 0;
    int healthy = 0;
    String patients = "";
    float temp = 0;
    double middleTemperature = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < temperatureData.length; i++) {
        patients+=temperatureData[i];
        temp+=temperatureData[i];
        if (temperatureData[i] >= 36.2 && temperatureData[i] <= 36.9) {
            healthy +=1;
            count+=1;
        }else {
            count+=1;
        }
    }

    double d = temp/count;
    middleTemperature = Math.rint(100.0*d)/100.0;

    String report =
            "Температуры пациентов: " + patients +

                    "\nСредняя температура: " + middleTemperature +

                    "\nКоличество здоровых: " + healthy;


    return report;
}
```

}
//Скажите что лишнее и куда смотреть внимательнее! Ошибка на выходе
//(Ожидает)Температуры пациентов: 32.1 33.1 32.5 33.5 34.5 36.5 38.5 39.5 33.3 32.7 36.9 36.5 34.3 37.5 //32.5 32.5 32.4 34.5 35.4 32.5 34.5 39.4 32.5 36.5 36.4 39.6 37.5 32.5 37.5 39.4
//Средняя температура: 35.23
//Количество здоровых: 5
//(Выдаёт)Температуры пациентов: //32.133.132.533.534.536.538.539.533.332.736.936.534.337.532.532.532.434.535.432.534.539.432.536.5//36.439.637.532.537.539.4
//Средняя температура: 35.23
//Количество здоровых: 4
[image: Main]

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется у вас все работает, может из-за некорректного вывода у вас такое мнение добавьте пробел `patients+=temperatureData[i] + " ";` и посмотрите